# android button onClick don't do anything

Tags: java, android, button

I'm trying to implement `onClick` function for a `Button` on a custom `Dialog` but nothing happen when i click on the `Button` .it's the `butEditAdd`

> **MainActivity.java :**

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        final AddDialog addDialog = new AddDialog(MainActivity.this);
        addDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialogedit);
        final Button butEditAdd =(Button)addDialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
        //final Button butEditAdd=addDialog.getAdd();
        addDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        butEditAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //addDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"It's working",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
        });
        addDialog.show();
    }
});
```

addDialog.java:

```
public class AddDialog extends Dialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{

Activity a;
Dialog d;
Button add , cancel;
RadioButton owes,lent ,money,things ;
EditText name ,amount,object,note;
Spinner spin;

public AddDialog(Activity c) {
    super(c);
    this.a = c;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v){

};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dialogedit);
    add=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
    cancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCancel);
    owes = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButtonOwes);
    lent = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButtonLent);
    money = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButtonAmount);
    things =(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButtonThings);
    name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editName);
    object = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextWhat);
    amount =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextAmount);
    note =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextNote);
    spin=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerdevise);

    owes.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                lent.setChecked(false);
        }
    });
    lent.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            owes.setChecked(false);
        }
    });
    money.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            things.setChecked(false);
            object.setEnabled(false);
            amount.setEnabled(true);
            spin.setEnabled(true);
            object.setText("");

        }
    });
    things.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            money.setChecked(false);
            object.setEnabled(true);
            amount.setEnabled(false);
            spin.setEnabled(false);
            amount.setText("");
        }
    });
    object.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            things.performClick();
            things.setChecked(true);
        }
    });

    amount.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            money.performClick();
            money.setChecked(true);

        }
    });
```

thanks for help!

Comment: try this :  final Button butEditAdd =(Button)addDialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);

Comment: I think it is wrong way of implementation if you are using dialog fragment

Comment: ok so how i need to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dialog fragment has separate set of life cycles.If you want to create a class adddialog,then extend dialog fragment and in oncreate of adddialog use setcontent view.

If you want to create simple dialog try this line of code.This will solve your problem.

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final Dialog addDialog = new Dialog(this);
            addDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialogedit);
            final Button butEditAdd =(Button)addDialog.findViewById(R.id.btn);
            //final Button butEditAdd=addDialog.getAdd();
            addDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            butEditAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //addDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"It's working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            addDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Change AddDialog to Dialog

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final Dialog addDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            addDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialogedit);
            final Button butEditAdd =(Button)addDialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
            addDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            butEditAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //addDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"It's working",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
            });
            addDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: it is a custom dialog so i have addDialog.java

Comment: can you post that addDialog class here?

Comment: checkout [this](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2013/02/13/extend-dialog-class-write-its-button-click-activity-interfaces-android/)

Comment: i tried to do like you show me but i have a problem : i want to write myDialog.dismiss(); in my OnClick but i cannot because myDialog not initialized yet and i cannot initialize it before because i need to initalize myOnClickListener to inisialize myDialog . do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

you need it like this

```
 final Button butEditAdd =(Button)addDialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
```

Comment: yes sorry i forgot this but even with the onClick not responding

Comment: i don't know it seems fine... my dialog work like this...maybe has something to do with the background? try removing it maybe for a test? :P

Comment: it dosen't change anything , i mean it's just more ugly but still not responding

Answer (score 1):

You should inflate the layout first, then find the view by its id.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogedit, null);
final Button butEditAdd =(Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);

.............

butEditAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           //do something
       }
    });
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

use `this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: Please try to explain what your code does. Thus other (future) users can also understand the soulution.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **setContentView(R.layout.dialogedit)** from your dialog **onCreate()**.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

And your rest of the code working fine.